# Precedence of set union, intersect, and difference?

Tags: notation, elementary-set-theory

Online, I have read contradicting opinions on whether `intersect` should take precedence over `union` (by analogy to logical `and` and `or`), or whether all set operators should have equal precedence.

Which way makes more sense and why?

And where does `difference` fit in?  (I'd say it should be equal precedence to `intersect` because `A - B = A intersect B'`.)

Comment: What do you mean with "precedence" here?

Comment: Yeah the connection with arithmetic operators is the second best guide. Usually you can just figure it out by looking at which bracketing make sense though.

Comment: @Rasmus: Operator precedence determines whether `A union B intersect C` is `(A union B) intersect C` or `A union (B intersect C)`.

Comment: I was half way through the first chapter of Stoll's Set Theory and Logic, when I realized he had not introduced a rule of precedence for intersection over union.  Before that, I would not have hesitated to say that intersection binds more closely than union.  To my knowledge there is a complete isomorphism between the logical operators $\wedge$, $\vee$ and the set operators $\cap$, $\cup$.  It would therefore stand to reason that the same evaluation rules should apply to both realms.  But that's an anthropological rather than a logical matter.  Perhaps we should, here and now, declare it so.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no sensible way of preferring one of intersection and union more than the other, since complement switches them.  I don't think you should assume an order at all and you should always use parentheses.

Answer (score 10):

Since there are contradicting opinions, I recommend assuming that whoever is reading your work assumes a different precedence order than you do, and using lots of parentheses.

Comment: Good rule of thumb, so ++.  But I was looking for arguments for why the precedence should be one way or the other if you got to choose.